# WeasyPrint not displaying PNG in saved PDF file (Flask app)

Tags: python, pdf, flask, png, weasyprint

I am creating a Flask app which displays some results and a graph of those results. I would like to make the results and graph available for download as a PDF. Using WeasyPrint, I am able to render the HTML results just fine. However, I cannot get the PNG to render. The PNG is saved in the "static" folder of my flask app.. I am using pythonanywhere for hosting.

Even locally I cannot get the PNG to render. I have looked through other posts about a similar problem and haven't been able to get any results by following their solutions. Here's a bit of what my code looks like:

```
def make_pdf(self):
    results = self.compute()
    graph = "file://fig1.png"
    html = render_template('result_pdf.html', form=self, results=results, graph=graph)
    pdf = HTML(string=html, base_url='/home/username/mysite/app/static/').write_pdf()
```

And inside of my html template to display the PNG:

```
<img src="{{ graph }}">
```

I have tried many variations on this, such as `<img src="file://{{ graph }}">` with no luck. I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that WeasyPrint supports file:// urls?

Comment: This is from the WeasyPrint docs:
"As any web renderer, WeasyPrint can reach files on the local filesystem using file:// URIs. These files can be shown in img or embed tags for example.

When WeasyPrint used on a server with HTML or CSS files from untrusted sources, this feature may be used to know if files are present on the server filesystem, and to embed them in generated documents."  https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#access-to-local-files

Comment: I just noticed that you're using just a filename for your file URL and you're missing a slash. Your URL should be something like "file:///home/your_username/dir1/dir2/fig.png" where you're using the full path to the file and the file exists.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Glenn. I tried "file:///home/username/mysite/app/static/fig1.png" with no luck unfortunately. It's a frustrating problem because I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. The whole time the issue was actually some of my HTML/CSS. I did a test and removed my div tags wrapping the img tags and just had the img alone inside of the body. The image then displayed fine. I'll tinker with sending over some CSS to see if it changes things.

Thanks for the help.